# ftdi d2xx conflict with ftdi_sio on linux - How to remove ftdi_sio automatically

Tags: linux, udev, usbserial, ftdi

I have a rf-reader with ftdio usb to serial chip. I was able to write a program to control it using ftdi d2xx library. So far so good.

The issue is that when the reader is reconnected to the PC I have to remove ftdi_sio and usbserial mods using this command:

```
sudo rmmod ftdi_sio
sudo rmmod usbserial
```

I can't use ftdi d2xx library to connect to the reader if I don't run the code.

I want to be able to add a udev rule so whenever the reader is connected kernel unload the ftdi_sio and usbserial (or not load them in first place)

I've added a new udev rul to /etc/udev/rules.d with name 99-ftdi-sio.rule

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6001",  RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'rmmod ftdi_sio && rmmod usbserial'"
```

but it's not working. Anyone has any ideas how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by using a different library. 
Instead of `d2xx` library, I started using `pylibftdi` which is based on `libftdi` and it's not sensitive to `ftdi_sio`.

Answer (score 5):

is idVendor and idProduct correct ?

Then try:

```
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6001", MODE="0666",  RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'rmmod ftdi_sio && rmmod usbserial'"
```

If you know the device number you can try this script instead:

```
RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo -n 1-1:1.0 > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/ftdi_sio/unbind'"
```

Comment: No luck. I've added that to `99-ftdi-sio.rule`, then tried reloading rules with `sudo udevadm control --reload-rules` then connected the device again, `lsmod | grep ftdi` still shows ftdi_sio and usbserial mods loaded.

Comment: Also, I got the vendor and product from lsusb: `Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 USB-Serial (UART) IC
` 0403 for vendor, 6001 for product.

Comment: File should be called _somename.rules_  not _.rule_   Try to unload only ftdi_sio at first. It worked for me. Also is **rmmod** visible or  should be **/sbin/rmmod** ?

Answer (score -2):

Insted of adding a new file .rules, i added that new rule line in the 70-persistent-ipoib.rules already existent and worked for me. :)