# Lattice Diamond v 3.11 on Linux: problem with ftdio_sio

Tags: lattice-diamond

On Linux, since v3.11, it seems that Lattice Diamond can only detect a FTDI cable if the kernel driver ftdio_sio has been removed.

On v3.10 and before, it was possible to just unbind the ftdi tty (ttyUSB*) with a udev rule (many blogs which explain how to install Diamond on Ubuntu mention such procedure - [example](https://ycnrg.org/lattice-diamond-on-ubuntu-16-04/)) and not to have to remove the ftdio_sio driver.

Does anyone know a way to still run the Lattice programmer without having to remove the ftdio_sio driver since v3.11?

Comment: are you sure that the driver has to be "removed" and not just unloaded?

Comment: By remove, I meant rmmod

Comment: did you check if the udev rule is still matching correctly?

Comment: Yes (of course...)

Comment: if it works with the manual "sudo rmmod" but not automatically via the udev rules chances are that the udev part is making trouble. Did you check the logs and monitor the "state" of the driver (i.e. check what driver is loaded after reboot, is anything unusual reported by udev, does diamond maybe try to unload the driver by itself and fails etc)?

Comment: @ChristianB. Are you a Lattice employee? The udev rule seems correct because it works with v3.10 on the same system and I see that ttyUSB0 is removed. My guess is that v3.11 (unlike v3.10) wants the full access to the FTDI chip and doesn't accept that another driver accesses it such as ftdio_sio.

Comment: no I am not. This is mostlikely the typical D2XX vs ftdio_sio conflict. You can find plenty of information about that. As long as the ftdio_sio is loaded the D2XX cannot be accessed. So in the end it is tedious "where does it go wrong" research you have to do and I cannot help you without details like systemlogs etc.

Comment: If you read a question like this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33981056/ftdi-d2xx-conflict-with-ftdi-sio-on-linux-how-to-remove-ftdi-sio-automatically), the solution was to change the library (aka. what Lattice Diamond uses internally), so it's unlikely that there is going to be an easy solution...

Comment: well the last answer should work according to the comments

Comment: Well, that's not the answer I want!!!