# Unable to open FTDI SPI interface

Tags: ubuntu, interface, spi, ftdi

I am trying to download [OpenTitan example](https://github.com/lowRISC/opentitan/releases/tag/snapshot-20191101-2) to Nexys Video Artix-7 FPGA board. I use Ubuntu16 as host to build OpenTitan. However I have met this message `Unable to open FTDI SPI interface.` How can I fix it. Thank you

Comment: The more information you give us the more likely someone can help you. Do you "see" the FT? As VCP or was the D2XX driver loaded? Chances are that your system automatically loaded the former while the latter is needed for SPI. For more details see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33981056/ftdi-d2xx-conflict-with-ftdi-sio-on-linux-how-to-remove-ftdi-sio-automatically

Answer (score 0):

I solved it just by reboot the server. At the time I posted this issue, I couldn't reboot the server because my co-workers were working on it.